# Does Amazon S3 use Cloudfront by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I would have assumed that S3 would use Cloudfront by default but I do not believe it does. I cannot find anyone definitely answering whether it does use cloudfront by default or not.

EX:

- Does going to https://mybucket.s3.aws.com/derp.png use the closest amazon server to decrease download times?

Comment: No - that's why it is a separate service with a separate charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Amazon S3 bucket exists in only **one region**. There are automatic redirects if a region isn't specified, but it always resolves to the S3 service in the bucket's specific region.

This is a very important feature of Amazon S3. If an organization is working under **Data Governance rules** that require data to stay within a certain country, then S3 meets this requirement nicely.

Amazon CloudFront is a web **caching service** that can sit *in front* of Amazon S3, Amazon EC2 and even external services. Data requests sent to CloudFront are forwarded to *origins*, which return the data. CloudFront then caches the information for future requests. Use of CloudFront is optional. Additional charges apply.